# How to send file from local computer to my server in php?

Tags: php, html, image, file-upload, ftp-client

I want to upload one image file(example - "C:\Users\Public\Pictures\1.png") to my ftp server(ftp://srict.96.lt).

I have the following HTML code which allows user to select the file from local computer.

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="imgup.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

now in the imgup.php I tried the following code but it says **"move_uploaded_file(/Hydrangeas.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/u704250527/public_html/imgup.php on line 21"**

```
<?php
        $target_dir = "public_html/";    /* I also tried for "/"  "root/public_html/" */
        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
        $uploadOk = 1;
        $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if ($uploadOk == 0) 
         {
            echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
        } 
        else 
        {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file))
            {
                echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
            }
           else 
            {
                echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
            }
        }
        ?>
```

I need the file to be uploaded when user clicks upload button.
 I also tried using ftp in php this also gives me the same error failed to open stream.

```
<?php
// connect and login to FTP server
$ftp_server = "ftp.srict.96.lt";
$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
$ftp_username="user";
$ftp_userpass="pass";
$login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);

$file = "D:\Picture1.png";
$fp = fopen($file,"r");
if (ftp_fput($ftp_conn, "1.png", $fp, FTP_ASCII))
  {
  echo "Successfully uploaded $file.";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error uploading $file.";
  }
ftp_close($ftp_conn); 
?>
```

Comment: You need to study about ftp

Comment: I also googled for this, everything says move_uploaded_file() will work. but it is not working for me. Can you give any resource for me to study? I am really interested to study that and work on this.

Comment: Actually that moves to your current server not the ftp.. server to move it to ftp server  you need to connect to ftp and then send them.. Read ftp using php

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI am I doing it correct. Is $file correctly given?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found what is wrong. The file which is uploaded has to selected and should be added using $_FILES['filetoupload']['tmp_name'];

This is the complete code below.

for HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="imgup.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Once user clicks uploads the following php script will execute and magic will happen.

```
<?php
// connect and login to FTP server
$ftp_server = "ftp.my.server.com";
$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
$ftp_username="my_username";
$ftp_userpass="my_password";
$login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);


var_dump($_FILES);
if (ftp_put($ftp_conn, "1.png",$_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], FTP_BINARY))
  {
  echo "Successfully uploaded $file.";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error uploading $file.";
  }

// close connection
ftp_close($ftp_conn); 
?>
```

This is the important line here This says to upload file using FTP_BINARY mode which is mostly preferred for image and document files. Also note "tmp_name" to upload.

**`ftp_put($ftp_conn, "1.png",$_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], FTP_BINARY)`**